# Avoid execution goes on in a .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a code like this one to see whether some radio buttons have been checked or not. I'm using .each function of jquery to show an alert when I find a group of radio buttons with the same name value and none of them have been checked. When I find one I want to fire an alert and return false, but after the alert is shown the execution of the .each stops but the lines after .each function are executed (I mean true value is executed).

```
$(":radio").each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var numAnswered = $(":radio").filter('[name='+name+']').filter(":checked").length;
    var notAnswered = numAnswered == 0;
    if(notAnswered){
        alert("Must answer all questions");
        return false;
    }
});
console.log('still goes here even when alert is fired');
return true;
```

How can I avoid this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you radio buttons group in another container of sort sort?  It would be much more efficient to loop that way, like `$(".container").each(...` then check `$(this).find(":radio:checked").length`, you'd be checking far fewer times overall.

Comment: @Nick Craver I know that it would be more efficient, but I don't want that this function rely on how the radio buttons are displayed on the html because it may be changed later and there may be more than a "radio group" in the same container.

Comment: As long as they're in a container of *some* sort you can identify, you can make it *much* more efficient, even if you did `$(":radio").closest("div").each(...)` to make it agnostic for example.

Comment: @Nick Craver ok, the problem is that now are in a table, but later can be in a div. I know I can use .closest("div") or .closest("table"), and I know that it is very inefficient to do in the way I'm doing. But I wanted to avoid that anyone would change the layout (the table for some divs) and forget to change it in this function, but maybe being more efficient is worth of taking the risk.

Comment: Whatever works, just putting it out there.  Just be aware that rarely can your JavaScript be DOM structure agnostic *and* efficient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myreturnvalue = true;
$(":radio").each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var numAnswered = $(":radio").filter('[name='+name+']').filter(":checked").length;
    var notAnswered = numAnswered == 0;
    if(notAnswered){
        alert("Must answer all questions");
        myreturnvalue = false;
        return false;
    }
});
console.log('still goes here even when alert is fired');
return myreturnvalue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use that same `notAnswered` variable (or another, whatever floats your boat) at a higher scope, like this:

```
var notAnswered;
$(":radio").each(function(){
    notAnswered = $(":radio[name="+this.name+"]:checked").length == 0;
    if(notAnswered){
        alert("Must answer all questions");
        return false;
    }
});
if(notAnswered) return false;
console.log("will only fire if there's an answer");
return true;
```

The other changes above are just slimming down the code, you can get away with far fewer selector engine invocations :)